# Opening Table-Form (from toolbar) with VBA Button Macro

Tags: vba, excel

How can I open the UserForm for tables that is built into the toolbar in Excel 365 and contains previous entries by using a macro attached to a button object?

I have tried recording the macro since this is very basic but the result when executed opens the form without any existing data. The recording gives:

```
Sub OpenForm()
' OpenForm Macro
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
End Sub
```

It Results in this:[This is the output from the recorded macro code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJOng.jpg)
When I select the table manually and then click the form button it opens like it should:[press this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApPNs.jpg) and [provide a result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XAIW.jpg).